# Make PFImageView Load Faster

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I have a tableview that displays user uploaded `PFImageViews`. But the images load slowly because they are high res.

What is the most efficient (least costly) way to make images load quickly, while keeping the image size the same.

#### Current Approach:

- Save the image twice (original file and low res file)
- When displaying `PFImageView`, display the low res image
  first, then asynchronously load the original image.

Is this the best approach?

Comment: Generate a set of low-res images appropriate for your app. Do not load hi-res image until you absolutely need it, e.g. for thumbnails it's better have a small version of picture available on backend. Parse-image allows you to resize and save images on Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Method 3:
For everything not in view of the user, do not load the images (delayed loader). That saves you the bandwidth and CPU to give the user the best possible experience.

Comment: Yes, the images currently don't load until within view. The problem is, once they do load, they load slowly.

Comment: Ok, the other way around: a pre-loader. Then you can utilize the time while the user is still busy with something else.

Last option is to re-save all images in an incremental image format. 
The option you mentioned is not actually faster, except that you have better control of what the user sees. In an incremental image format (progressive jpeg for example), you do not have the control, but it uses less bandwidth than your initial idea of low and high res version